# Derivation of the Fokker-Planck Equation from the Master Eq

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I have a master equation -

$$\frac{\partial P(n,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}[(n+1)Pr(n+1,t)+(N-n+1)Pr(n-1,t)-NPr(n,t)]$$

I would like to take this master equation and convert it into a Fokker-Planck equation. I consider a variable $x=\frac{2n}{N}$ so that at steady state I would get $<x>=1$.

I tried doing some manipulations on this equation to get to the form where I can perform a taylor expansion, but I'm just not getting there. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

I consider $N = N-n+n+1-1 $ to simplify some terms..

$$\frac{\partial P(n,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}[(n+1)Pr(n+1,t)+(N-n+1)Pr(n-1,t)-(N-)Pr(n,t)]$$

$$\frac{\partial P(n,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}[(n+1)Pr(n+1,t)-(n+1)Pr(n,t)]+\frac{1}{2}[(N-n+1)Pr(n-1,t)-(N-n-1)Pr(n,t)]$$

^ Can't simplify from here...

Different try?

$$\frac{\partial P(n,t)}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}[(n+1)Pr(n+1,t)-nPr(n,t)]+\frac{1}{2}[(N-n+1)Pr(n-1,t)-(N-n)Pr(n,t)]$$

Not sure how to take care of this either.